# Locale Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a site with various routes including languages:

eg:

```
/aboutus (english no language in the url)
/es/aboutus
/nl/aboutus
```

Here is my problem:
I create a language switcher in a twig template, and it works when I am on the ES page for example:

```
{% set lng = '/' ~ app.request.locale ~ '/' %}

<li>
  <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params'))|replace({ (lng): '/'}) }}">
    <i class="cus-gb"></i> 
    English
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'es'})) }}">
    <i class="cus-es"></i> 
    Spanish
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'nl'})) }}">
    <i class="cus-nl"></i> 
    Dutch
  </a>
</li>
```

But it doesn't work when I am on the EN page because the `_locale` is not in the URL. My routes:

```
_event_translate:
  path:  /{_locale}/{nameid}
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Event:index, _locale: en }
  requirements: 
    _locale: es|nl 
_event_default:
  path:  /{nameid}
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Event:index, _locale: en }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to simple create all links the same way, with merge({'_locale': 'xy'}), like this:

```
<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"><i class="cus-gb"></i> English</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'es'})) }}"><i class="cus-es"></i> Spanish</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'nl'})) }}"><i class="cus-nl"></i> Dutch</a></li>
```

It should work.

**[EDIT]:**

And add `en` to route

```
_event_translate:
  path:  /{_locale}/{nameid}
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Event:index, _locale: en }
  requirements: 
    _locale: es|nl|en
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as my routes are not setup to pickup en as a language, I wanted to use the default en language and only for another language use the local param.

Comment: If you add `en` and set `_locale: en` the url locale will only appear with `es` and `nl` languages

Comment: Thanks, but in the menu it is still showing /en/ and I would like to remove this for the English page. Also when I access the english page like / the menu doesn't give me the correct urls in the languages as it goes through: _event_default:

Answer (score 1):

I use language switcher like this and it works very well:

```
{% set requestParams = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
{% set requestRoute = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
{% set locale = app.request.locale %}

<div class="language-icons">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(requestRoute, requestParams|merge({'_locale' : 'en'})) }}">en</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(requestRoute, requestParams|merge({'_locale' : 'fr'})) }}">fr</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(requestRoute, requestParams|merge({'_locale' : 'ru'})) }}">ru</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After that you should define `_locale` in each route where the translation should be applied:

```
_event_translate:
  path:  /{_locale}/{nameid}
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Event:index, _locale: en }
  requirements: 
    _locale: es|nl 
_event_default:
  path:  /{_locale}/{nameid}
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Event:index, _locale: en }
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't work, I get an error message: `code`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "_locale" for route "_event_translate" must match "es|nl" ("en" given) to generate a corresponding URL.")`code`

Comment: @SymonSays The exception is thrown because you have condition in your `_event_translate` path `requirements: _locale: es|nl`. You should remove it and use fallback locale instead http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#fallback-translation-locales

Comment: Thanks, I did add a fallback local, and removing the requirements didn't do the trick unfortunately. The main problem is that the /en/ get's added to the url and for english I would like to have this removed.